# Sort array by filename in groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy

I'm trying to sort a list of jars by their filenames:

```
def jars = ['app-5.0.0.jar', 'app-5.1.1.jar', 'app-5.2.0-9.jar', 'app-5.2.0-10.jar', 'app-5.2.0.jar', 'app-5.1.0.jar']
jars = jars.sort().reverse()
println jars
```

The result is:

```
[app-5.2.0.jar, app-5.2.0-9.jar, app-5.2.0-10.jar, app-5.1.1.jar, app-5.1.0.jar, app-5.0.0.jar]
```

However, I'm more interested in the *natural* (and probably more intuitive) sorting to receive this sorted list:

```
[app-5.2.0-10.jar, app-5.2.0-9.jar, app-5.2.0.jar, app-5.1.1.jar, app-5.1.0.jar, app-5.0.0.jar]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

this is my current algorithm for sorting but it's too verbose in my opinion. However, it really does what I'm looking for. Each part of the version (major, minor, maintenance, build) is evaluated independently:

```
jars = jars.sort { a, b ->
    File fileA = new File(a)
    File fileB = new File(b)
    def partsA = fileA.name.findAll(/\d+/)
    def partsB = fileB.name.findAll(/\d+/)

    if (partsA[0] == null) partsA[0] = "0"
    if (partsB[0] == null) partsB[0] = "0"
    if (partsA[0].toInteger() < partsB[0].toInteger()) {
        println "${partsA[0]} < ${partsB[0]}"
        return -1
    } else if (partsA[0].toInteger() > partsB[0].toInteger()) {
        println "${partsA[0]} > ${partsB[0]}"
        return 1
    } else {
        if (partsA[1] == null) partsA[1] = "0"
        if (partsB[1] == null) partsB[1] = "0"
        if (partsA[1].toInteger() < partsB[1].toInteger()) {
            println "${partsA[1]} < ${partsB[1]}"
            return -1
        } else if (partsA[1].toInteger() > partsB[1].toInteger()) {
            println "${partsA[1]} > ${partsB[1]}"
            return 1
        } else {
            if (partsA[2] == null) partsA[2] = "0"
            if (partsB[2] == null) partsB[2] = "0"
            if (partsA[2].toInteger() < partsB[2].toInteger()) {
                println "${partsA[2]} < ${partsB[2]}"
                return -1
            } else if (partsA[2].toInteger() > partsB[2].toInteger()) {
                println "${partsA[2]} > ${partsB[2]}"
                return 1
            } else {
                if (partsA[3] == null) partsA[3] = "0"
                if (partsB[3] == null) partsB[3] = "0"
                if (partsA[3].toInteger() < partsB[3].toInteger()) {
                    println "${partsA[3]} < ${partsB[3]}"
                    return -1
                } else if (partsA[3].toInteger() > partsB[3].toInteger()) {
                    println "${partsA[3]} > ${partsB[3]}"
                    return 1
                } else {
                    println "${partsA[3]} = ${partsB[3]}"
                    return 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5105309110501376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
def jars = ['app-5.0.0.jar', 'app-5.1.1.jar', 'app-5.2.0-9.jar', 'app-5.2.0-10.jar', 'app-5.2.0.jar', 'app-5.1.0.jar', 'app-5.1.1-172.jar']

// it is probably sufficient to just choose a "high enough" number
// (e.g. 10) instead of resolving max digits.
def maxDigits = jars*.findAll(/\d+/).flatten()*.size().max()

// sort the strings consisting of left-padded version numbers
// e.g. sorting string for 'app-5.1.1-172.jar' is '  5  1  1172'
jars.sort{ it.findAll(/\d+/)*.padLeft(maxDigits).join() }

println 'max digits: ' + maxDigits
println jars.reverse()
```

Output:

```
max digits: 3
[app-5.2.0-10.jar, app-5.2.0-9.jar, app-5.2.0.jar, app-5.1.1-172.jar, app-5.1.1.jar, app-5.1.0.jar, app-5.0.0.jar]
```

Answer (score 3):

Had to try this:

```
def jars = ['app-5.0.0.jar', 'app-5.1.1.jar', 'app-5.2.0-9.jar', 'app-5.2.0-10.jar', 'app-5.2.0.jar', 'app-5.1.0.jar', 'app-1.0.jar', 'app-0.10.jar']
jars = jars.sort{ -it.findAll( /\d+/ ).join().toInteger() }
println jars
```

Gets:

```
[app-5.2.0-10.jar, app-5.2.0-9.jar, app-5.2.0.jar, app-5.1.1.jar, app-5.1.0.jar, app-5.0.0.jar, app-1.0.jar, app-0.10.jar]
```

Or more thorough version that handles large patch versions:

```
def jars = ['app-5.0.0.jar', 'app-5.1.1.jar', 'app-5.2.0-9.jar', 'app-5.2.0-10.jar', 'app-5.2.0.jar', 'app-5.1.0.jar', 'app-5.1.1-172.jar']

jars.sort{ a, b -> 
    def aList = a.findAll(/\d+/)
    def bList = b.findAll(/\d+/)

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < aList.size() ; i++ ) {
        def aVal = aList[i] ? aList[i].toInteger() : 0
        def bVal = bList[i] ? bList[i].toInteger() : 0
        if ( aVal <=> bVal ) { // only return if non-zero i.e. not equal
            return aVal <=> bVal
        }
    }

    bList.size() > aList.size() ? -1 : 0 // all facets match up to now, if b has additional parts it must be later version
}

println jars.reverse()
```

Gets:

```
[app-5.2.0-10.jar, app-5.2.0-9.jar, app-5.2.0.jar, app-5.1.1-172.jar, app-5.1.1.jar, app-5.1.0.jar, app-5.0.0.jar]
```

Comment: How about 'app-5.1.1-172.jar' which could be possible too? I like your solution but let's try to make it a tad more robust. every part (a.b.c-d) should  represent a number and numbers shall be compared from major version (a) to build-number (d) successively. I'll investigate in a proper regex myself in the meantime.

Comment: see my updated question. Now it does exactly what I'm looking for but it's still extremely verbose compared to your solution. Do you see a possibility to compact my code anyhow?